# Объединение классов

Tags: css, css3

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки одновременно увеличивался и круг, и треугольник?

```css
.btn-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn-2-triangle {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  left: 12.3px;
  right: 11.3px;
  bottom: 11.3px;
}

.btn-2:active {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn-2-triangle:active {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 5.3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5.3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10.6px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 14.6px;
  left: 16.4px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-2-1">
  <div class="btn-2">
    <div class="btn-2-triangle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код нужно как фрагмент вставлять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смените селектор:

```
.btn-2-triangle:active
```

Который значит "Нажатый треугольник" - смените на:

```
.btn-2:active .btn-2-triangle
```

Который значит "Треугольник внутри нажатой кнопки".

```css
.btn-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn-2-triangle {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  left: 12.3px;
  right: 11.3px;
  bottom: 11.3px;
}

.btn-2:active {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn-2:active .btn-2-triangle {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 5.3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5.3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10.6px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 14.6px;
  left: 16.4px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-2-1">
  <div class="btn-2">
    <div class="btn-2-triangle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn-2-triangle {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  left: 12.3px;
  right: 11.3px;
  bottom: 11.3px;
}

.btn-2:active {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn-2:active > .btn-2-triangle {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 5.3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5.3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10.6px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 14.6px;
  left: 16.4px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-2-1">
  <div class="btn-2">
    <div class="btn-2-triangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```